# Asp.Net publish on server does not some html controls

Tags: iis

I have a web application which works fine when i publish and host it on my localhost ...
The same published folder i host to a remote server and a few controls go missing on load of the page .I log into remote desktop to the server and try opening the site on the server itself it works fine. But only when i access it from my local system some controls go missing .Is there something i am missing on the Browserused on the swerver as well as my local system is IE 8 .

Thanks & Regards,
Francis P.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some URLs with a hard-coded `http://localhost/...`.

Change all of your absolute URLs to relative URLs.

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) will be very helpful to see which URLs are being requested.